# Change text color of UISegmentedControl for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to Objective C, need to change only the text color of a UISegmentedControl to white color, with the tint color is black opacity reduced. However this works on iPhone but on iPad the text color is not coming properly. It takes the tint color for its font also.
Below is the code i have used.

```
[ segCtrl setTintColor:[ UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.15 ] ];

[ segCtrl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0 ];

[ segCtrl setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[ UIFont fontWithName:FONTNAME size:13.0 ], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor ]} forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
```

How can i fix this. And why the same code differs in both devices.

Below are the images I get from iPhone and iPad

[image: iPhone][image]

Comment: comment the first line and then check

Comment: commenting TintColor brings default blue color also the textattributes did not work. The text is also in blue color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put below code in viewdidload :

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

use this code:
[UISegmentedControl_Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html)

into viewDidLoad function.

```
// color selected text ---> red
    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor] } forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    // color disabled text ---> blue
    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor] } forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // color tint segmented control ---> Your color
    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTintColor:[ UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.15 ]];
```

Comment: I tried the code but still the text color is set to tint color.
    [segCtrl setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:FONTNAME size:13.0],
                                          NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
                                          NSShadowAttributeName:[ UIColor whiteColor ]}
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: @Jaff `segCtrl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;` It's required for the tintColor to work.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include your comment about segmentedControlStyle so others don't have to dig through the comments if they stumble upon this answer.

Comment: @Yuyutsu I tried and its not working also i get the warning depricated